# How can reflection be used on satellite assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, assemblies, satellite-assembly

How can reflection be used on satellite assemblies? is there any difference in reflecting on normal assemblies and satellite assemblies?

Kindly supplement your answers with examples and refernces.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK satellite assemblies don't contain any code, thus there is nothing to reflect on.
They contain only localized resources, which can be accessed via ResourceManager class with appropriate culture.

Comment: Then how can the details of satellite assembly be taken at run time?

Comment: What details do you want? It is just a container for strings, images, etc with specified culture. You can get all of them via ResourceManager.